# Declare Trix for Canada?

Tags: canada, food-and-drink

I'm visiting some friends in Canada (I'm from the United States) and they told me that [Trix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trix_(cereal)) is no longer sold there, and that I should bring them some for the sake of nostalgia.

When looking up information on why Trix is not be sold in Canada, I found two reasons; that Trix just isn't sold there anymore (seeming like a company choice), and that it is banned from being sold because it contains BHT.

I'm not sure which is correct, but I've been searching to see if there is any information on whether it would be banned from entering Canada... So I'm wondering if it is safe to declare and bring with me? I will be entering via vehicle from the United States.

Comment: Another reason I have not to like cereals...

Comment: @pnuts Still is being called breakfast cereal and I still don't like it....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[Silly rabbit, Trix are for Americans!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=if-_DOl6PJ8)*

Or maybe not.  Butylated hydroxytoluene (BHT) appears in Health Canada's "[Food additives permitted for use](http://www.hc-sc.gc.ca/fn-an/securit/addit/list/11-preserv-conserv-eng.php#a4)" list, with a specific permission for "Dried breakfast cereals".  So unless they're wildly exceeding the limits, it seems unlikely that Trix would be banned for this, even though that chemical name sounds [paint-thinner-o-licious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toluene).

In general, if you have the slightest doubt, declaring is always the safer route: much better to have something confiscated than be busted for smuggling.

That said, I can't really see Canadian Customs being too bothered by a box of cereal, and there's no need to be too specific.  I'd just ask something like "Hey, do I need to declare any food I've got with me?", and when they ask what, "A box of cereal".  Odds are pretty darn high they'll wave you on.

Comment: +1 "Silly rabbit, Trix are for Americans!" (C'mon, we all know that you knew someone was gonna comment this...)

Comment: I grew up being force-fed those commercials on TV.  Don't think I've ever actually eaten the stuff though, multicolored cereal scares me...

Comment: In their defense, I like them all. ;)

Comment: Be aware that most people, like me, don't get the joke. I don't even know what "Trix" is...

Comment: Fair call.  Added a link to one of those annoying commercials, which have apparently been running for a *lot* longer than I thought...